# Viewing a Base64 encoded image when string is send via socket

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to send an image from one pc to another with encryption. I am encoding it on the sender machine and it reaches the receiver machine, no problem.
However, when I try to decode it, it seems to always return errors...

```
while True:
    data = connection.recv(2000000)
    if data:
      b= data.decode("utf-8")
      b=decrypt(b,key)
      print(b)
      with open('encode.bin', "wb") as file:
          file.write(b)
      file = open('encode.bin', 'rb')
      byte = file.read()
      file.close()

      decodeit = open('camera.jpeg', 'wb')
      decodeit.write(base64.b64decode((byte)))
      decodeit.close()
```

Printing b gives me: `b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ......oooA/9k='`
which I believe is fine and normal, because when I paste it in an online Base64 str to img tool I get the picture I send. The error is:
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` and it referes to `file.write(b)` line....
I can't figure out what is the problem, however, I strongly believe that it is not due to the encryption-decryption. Probably has to do with how the string data is handled.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Decoding a bytestring as UTF-8 gives you a string. You might be seeing a print from somewhere else as that `print(b)` should print a string. And that's why `file.write(b)` complains. It is expecting bytes but `b` is a string.

Comment: Should I just delete the .decode() part;

Comment: I somehow missed the `decrypt` line. I would need to see that it does too know got sure. But if it returns a string, encoding back to utf-8 night be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to pull it off, I removed the first two letters (apparently the b') and the last character(') and it worked just fine!

```
      b = b[2:size - 1]
      try:
        image = base64.b64decode(b, validate=True)
        with open("camera.jpeg", "wb") as f:
              f.write(image)
```